# Django makemigrations app order

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm using Django 1.8.4. As my project is still under construction, I frequently remove all migration scripts, and rerun `makemigrations` to generate the initial migration scripts.
I found `makemigrations` would generate two migration scripts for one of my apps while other apps just have `0001_initial.py`. It would be something like:

```
- 0001_initial.py
- 0002_auto_20150919_1645.py
```

I checked the content of `0002_auto_20150919_1645.py`, it was adding foreign field from the other app's model.
I guess it might be related to the order of creating migrations for apps. So I delete these two migration scripts of this app and then run `makemigrations` again. Now I have only one migration script for this app.

My questions is:
    Is there any way I can control the order `makemigrations` create migrations for apps?

For example, I have two apps, `app1` and `app2`, and `app1` depends on `app2`. Is it possible `makemigrations` create migration for `app2` first, and then `app1`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can manually run migrations for an individual app.

```
./manage.py makemigrations app2
./manage.py makemigrations app1
./manage.py makemigrations # migrate the rest of your apps
```

You could also [squash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) your existing migrations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good solution for my situation while the `./manage.py migrate ` should be `./manage.py makemigrations`. Just wondering if Django has any configuration to control this order instead of manually running `makemigrations` for the apps.

Comment: But it also detects changes in other apps